# Azure resources: IaaS - PaaS - SaaS

Tags: azure, resources

I'm new to Azure. I have finished reading the azure-fundamentals Learning module, and I have a free Azure account.
Azure offers several services of three different types: IaaS - PaaS - SaaS
I'm confused about there is nothing that bind each resource to the type of service.
Can someone explain me why?

Comment: Your question is very vague, can you be more clear what you are looking for?

Comment: I'm preparing the Microsoft exam "Azure foundamentals" and some questions are about "migrate an on-premise infrastructure to Azure using only (for example)  PaaS resources". But on Azure portal nothing tells if a resource is PaaS, Iaas or Saas. I found this really irritating.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to know for sure what kind various Azure services are, is to go to the [Azure Documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/?product=featured) and click through some (or all) of them to learn more about each and every one of them.

Microsoft also has three pages summarizing these three types:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/overview/what-is-iaas/

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/overview/what-is-paas/

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/overview/what-is-saas/